# How do I force my Chromebook to boot from linux install on the internal hard drive?

Tags: linux, chrome-os, chrome-book

### Background

I installed Linux on the internal hard drive of my Chromebook and now, every time I boot up, I am forced to press the `ctrl-l` combination to select which media device I would like to boot from in the BIOS screen.

### Question

Is there a way where I can skip the step having to press `ctrl-l` to select the internal hard drive to boot from on my Chromebook?

Comment: what hapens if you do not press the key combination?

Comment: @jsotola it sits on the recovery screen since it's in developer mode